# angular service to controller

Tags: angularjs, http, service, controller

I am struggling with a service to controller. I used to put my http request on my controller before, but now I want to improve and put http request on service. But i can't find out what is not working

In my controller

```
function testCtrl($scope,notify,UserLog) {
$scope.people = {};
    $scope.people = UserLog.getUser();
};
```

In my service

```
.module('mymodule')
.service('UserLog',function($http){
function getUser(callback) {

var objUserInfo = new ActiveXObject("WScript.network");
var uname =  objUserInfo.UserName
var params= "/php/content_user_log.php?uid=" + uname

        $http.get(params).
            success(function(data, status) {
                callback(data,status);
                return data;

        }).

            error(function(data,status){
                callback(data,status);
                return data;
            });
        }
```

});

I tired both callback method and / or return data but I have same output from the console

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'gestUser'
```

Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare members in this way. You must add it on the `prototype` instead of the `scope`, like the following example:

```
.module('mymodule')
  .service('UserLog', function($http) {
    this.getUser = function(callback) {

      var objUserInfo = new ActiveXObject("WScript.network");
      var uname = objUserInfo.UserName;
      var params = "/php/content_user_log.php?uid=" + uname

      $http.get(params)
        .success(function(data, status) {
          callback(data, status);
          return data;

        })
        .error(function(data, status) {
          callback(data, status);
          return data;
        });
    };    
  });
```

Also, consider using a promise being resolved with the desired data instead of using a calback parameter, handling status and request is not responsibility of controllers:

```
.module('mymodule')
  .service('UserLog', function($http) {
    this.getUser = function() {

      var objUserInfo = new ActiveXObject("WScript.network");
      var uname = objUserInfo.UserName;
      var params = "/php/content_user_log.php?uid=" + uname

      return $http.get(params)
        .then(function(data, status) {
          return data;    
        });
    };    
  });
```

Then call it like so:

```
UserLog.getUser()    
    .then(function (user) {        
        $scope.user = user;        
    });
```